# Why `executeNonQueryPlan failed` error occurred when importing data by csv files into Apache IoTDB?

Tags: import, apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I imported data into the Apache IoTDB database through csv files, I used the following code to create the metadata according to the instructions in the user manual: `SET STORAGE GROUP TO root.W3.ECMS, CREATE TIMESERIES root.W3.ECMS.YC0056 WITH DATATYPE=DOUBLE ,ENCODING=GORILLA`. The header is written as `Time,root.W3.ECMS.YCe856.double`, but an error is reported when importing: `Meet error when insert csv because 500: [INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR(500)] Exception occurred: executeNonQueryPlan failed. current node YC0056 is a MeasurementMNode, can not get Device Template`. Anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write the wrong header, therefore Apache IoTDB conduct this error. Try to eliminate `.double` from the header and see if this problem has been solved.